# How to pass an value of lightning-input-address to apex class?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, geolocation, wire, address

I'm trying to find Opportunity records with an address within X amount of miles from an entered location. I'm using the lightning-input-address and passing the value to an Apex class and am getting this error - "AuraEnabled methods do not support parameter type of System.Address ". Is there any workaround to this?

LWC snippet:

```
<lightning-input-address
     class="location" value={location}
     address-label="Address" street-label="Street"
     city-label="City" country-label="Country"
     province-label="State" postal-code-label="Zip/ Postal Code"
     onchange={handleAddressChange} address-lookup-placeholder = "Search Address..."
     show-address-lookup>
</lightning-input-address>


@wire(getAddy, {location: '$location', allData: '$allData', distance: '$distance'})
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {...}
```

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getLocation(Address location, List<Opportunity> allData, Integer distance) {
  //  Address addr = location;
    Double lat = location.latitude;
    Double lon = location.longitude;
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT ID, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE DISTANCE(Hospital_Location__c, GEOLOCATION(:lat,:lon), 'mi') < :distance AND Id IN :allData]);
    return oppList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just define a custom class to use instead.

```
public class LatLong
{
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal latitude { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Change your parameter type from `Address` to `LatLong`, and it should fix the error you received. You can make it an inner class to your controller, or a top level class if you believe you may use this approach in multiple places.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something but how is the "location" param passed? It's a System.Address type.

Comment: What I'm saying is you should simply change that type to this custom type, which you should define.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the answer I will provide will actually get you a solution.

In your handleAddressChange you can capture the additional details of the address and then you can pass these into your Apex class.

So you can see below:

```
handleAddressChange(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.street);
    console.log(event.detail.city);
    console.log(event.detail.province);
    console.log(event.detail.postalCode);
    console.log(event.detail.country);
}
```

However I think you are actually after a latitude and longitude and I do not think that the lightning-input-address actually provides this.